# Why does a call stack differs when returning or storing

Tags: python, recursion

I am following a DP&recursion course with JS as the teaching language,
but I encountered some differences with Python..

When returning the call stack, everything goes as it should,
meaning the values in the stack are returning as a whole array:
(the following problem is about finding a combination of elements in the array that sums to totalsum)

```
def best_sum(totalsum, arr):

    if totalsum == 0:
        return []
    if totalsum < 0:
        return None

    for num in arr:
        remainder = totalsum - num

        results = best_sum(remainder, arr)

        if results is not None:
            return [*results, num]

    return None


print(best_sum(7, [2,3,4]))
```

The output here is:

```
[3, 2, 2]
```

But, when I try to save the call stack to an array, I only get 1 item per line:

```
    if results is not None:
        comb = [*results, num]
        print(comb)
```

Output:

```
[3]
[2]
[2]
```

My answer is.. is there a way to wait for the call stack to finish, before printing the results?
Because I would like to use that array "comb" to do further coding, but I can't since it fills completely only when returned..

I think I misinterpreted something about how a call stack works in Python :)

Answer (score 1):

> But, when I try to save the call stack to an array, I only get 1 item per line:

You changed more than only that. You also removed the `return` statement. So now the `for` loop is not interrupted, and the function will now `return None`... a different return value than intended.

That you only get to print lists with one item, is because the base case of your code is still executed correctly, as it returns `[]`. And `[*results, num]` is therefor equal to `[num]`. But that is as far as it goes as now your function can only return `[]` or `None`, nothing else. This is why you only see lists with one element in your output.

Once you reinstate that `return` (like `return comb`), it will work better. The logic of `if results is not None` depends on those `return` statements. Printing is not a replacement for a return value when the caller is going to check the return value like it does with that `if`.